# Why Class.forName("BumpTest"), not BumpTest.class?

Tags: java, language-specifications

In [JLS Sec 8.4.3.6, `synchronized` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6), it says:

> ```
> class BumpTest {
>     // ...
>     static synchronized void classBump() {
>         classCount++;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> has exactly the same effect as:
>
> ```
> class BumpTest {
>     // ...
>     static void classBump() {
>         try {
>             synchronized (Class.forName("BumpTest")) {
>                 classCount++;
>             }
>         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
>     }
> }
> ```

This looks odd to me, not to mention over-complicated: why use `Class.forName("BumpTest")`, not `BumpTest.class`? It's not possible that `BumpTest` isn't loaded, because it's executing code from that class, after all. And writing it as it is, the checked `ClassNotFoundException` has to be caught and swallowed.

Is there a particular reason to write it in this way?

Comment: Maybe the example predates class literals. I'm not sure when class literals were introduced.

Comment: Basically, you're saying that if you just use with `BumpTest.class` instead of `Class.forName`? Have you tried it? Maybe their example is not the best one

Comment: @user2357112 you are probably right: this example is in [the Java 1.0 spec](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/8.doc.html#55408), but there is no mention of class literals. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to just be a really, really old example, older than class literals. The same example appears in the [JLS 1.0](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/8.doc.html#55408), before class literals were introduced.